# Alter and Assign Object Without Side Effects

Tags: javascript

I currently have the following code:

```
var myArray = [];
var myElement = {
  id: 0,
  value: 0
}

myElement.id = 0;
myElement.value = 1;
myArray[0] = myElement;

myElement.id = 2;
myElement.value = 3;
myArray[1] = myElement;
```

The problem is that when I change the value of `id` and `value` for my second element, the values also change in the first element. Is there a way that I can keep adding new elements without it changing the value of the previously inserted values in the array?

Answer (score 74, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
var myArray = [];

myArray.push({ id: 0, value: 1 });
myArray.push({ id: 2, value: 3 });
```

or will this not work for your situation?

Answer (score 16):

This is a textbook case for a [constructor function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide/Working_with_Objects#Using_a_constructor_function):

```
var myArray = [];

function myElement(id, value){
    this.id = id
    this.value = value
}

myArray[0] = new myElement(0,1)
myArray[1] = new myElement(2,3)
// or myArray.push(new myElement(1, 1))
```

Comment: I Already implemented the other answer but I do agree that this is also a good solution. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You either need to keep creating new objects, or clone the existing one. See [What is the most efficient way to deep clone an object in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-clone-a-javascript-object) for how to clone.

Answer (score 1):

That's because object values are passed by reference. You can clone the object like this:

```
var myArray = [];
var myElement = {
  id: 0,
  value: 0
}

myElement.id =0;
myElement.value=1;
myArray[0] = myElement;

var obj = {};
obj = clone(myElement);
obj.id = 2;
obj.value = 3; 

myArray[1] = obj;

function clone(obj){
  if(obj == null || typeof(obj) != 'object')
    return obj;

  var temp = new obj.constructor(); 
  for(var key in obj)
    temp[key] = clone(obj[key]);

  return temp;
}    

console.log(myArray[0]);
console.log(myArray[1]);
```

**Result:**

```
 - id: 0
 - value: 1
 - id: 2
 - value: 3
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using jQuery, you can use [extend](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/)

```
myElement.id =0;
myElement.value=1;
myArray[0] = $.extend({}, myElement);

myElement.id = 2;
myElement.value = 3;
myArray[1] = $.extend({}, myElement);
```

Answer (score 0):

Objects are passed by reference.. To create a *new* object, I follow this approach..

```
//Template code for object creation.
function myElement(id, value) {
    this.id = id;
    this.value = value;
}
var myArray = [];

//instantiate myEle
var myEle = new myElement(0, 0);
//store myEle
myArray[0] = myEle;

//Now create a new object & store it
myEle = new myElement(0, 1);
myArray[1] = myEle;
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have the same object two times in your array, because object values are passed by reference. You have to create a new object like this

```
myElement.id = 244;
myElement.value = 3556;
myArray[0] = $.extend({}, myElement); //for shallow copy or
myArray[0] = $.extend(true, {}, myElement); // for deep copy
```

or

myArray.push({ id: 24, value: 246 });