# How to access and store an array of objects in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have these objects that are stored in array :

```
var current = [{1:{X:"",Y:""},2:{X:"",Y:""},3:{X:"",Y:""}},
           {1:{X:"",Y:""},2:{X:"",Y:""},3:{X:"",Y:""}},
           {1:{X:"",Y:""},2:{X:"",Y:""},3:{X:"",Y:""}}
           ];
```

What I want is to store them dynamically and access them dynamically after passing the objects value in a function.

```
function getXAxis(num){
//any
}

function getYAxis(num){
//any
}

trial1a.X = getXAxis(current[0][1].X);
trial1a.Y = getYAxis(current[0][1].Y);
trial2a.X = getXAxis(current[0][2].X);
trial2a.Y = getYAxis(current[0][2].Y);
trial3a.X = getXAxis(current[0][3].X);
trial3a.Y = getYAxis(current[0][3].Y);
trial1b.X = getXAxis(current[1][1].X);
trial1b.Y = getYAxis(current[1][1].Y);
```

What is the best way to access `current` values and store them dynamically as well

Comment: It's not clear to me what the issue is. You are already accessing the values in `current`.

Comment: Please note in your definition you're using capital `"X"`, `"Y"` but when trying to lookup you're using lower `"x"`, `"y"`

Comment: @FelixKling I'm accessing them but not dynamically

Comment: Then use a variable instead of any of the numbers. E.g. `current[i]`, where `i` gets its value from wherever. Is that what you are asking for? If you have ever iterated over an array with a `for` loop, you know how to access an array "dynamically".

Comment: Regarding adding: [Add new object to array](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9543805/218196).

Comment: "dynamically" in the sense that I don't need to declare trial1a.x... one by one

Comment: So you actually want to *create variables* dynamically? That's almost always a bad idea. You should have an array of `trial` elements instead (but then again you already have an array of objects). Not really sure where you are going with all of this.... maybe you are rather looking for `.map`? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want is to have your `trials` be dynamically generated?

Something like this should do what you want:

```
var trials = [];
for (var i = 0; i < current.length; i++) {
    trials[i] = {};
    for (var j in current[i]) {
        trials[i][j] = {
            X: getXAxis(current[i][j].X),
            Y: getYAxis(current[i][j].Y)
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: Use a normal `for` loop to iterate over the array.

Comment: `for... in` works for arrays, too, but changed, nevertheless

Comment: what is trials[i] = trials[i] || {}; for?

Comment: @ThomasM.- That's initialization of the index -  ensuring that the index is set in the trials array before it's accessed when we set `trials[i][j]`.  If you don't initialize it, JS will throw an error.

Comment: @ThomasM.- In thinking about it, the conditional isn't necessary.  Changed it to just set the index to an object.

Answer (score 0):

I guess I know what you are looking for..

```
var root = {};
function setValueInDeepStructure(value, path, tree) {  
  var thisStep = path.shift();
  if (path.length == 0) {
    tree[thisStep] = value;
  } else {
    if (!tree[thisStep]) {
      tree[thisStep] = {};
    }

    setValueInDeepStructure(value, path, tree[thisStep]);
  }
}

function getValueFromDeepStructure(path, tree) {
  var thisStep = path.shift();
  if (path.length == 0)
    return tree[thisStep];
  else
    return getValueFromDeepStructure(path, tree[thisStep]);
}

setValueInDeepStructure({x: 3, y: 5}, [0,1,5,6], root);
setValueInDeepStructure(7, [0,1,5,6,'x'], root);

getValueFromDeepStructure([0,1,5,6], root) // => {x:7, y:5}
```