# Get input value by looping name selector

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to loop through a list of element which have dynamic name's value, like item1,item2 etc. but I got undefined like below.

```js
len = $('.aws').length + 1;

var obj = [],
  temp = {};

for (var i = 1; i <= len; i++) {
  console.log(i)
  temp["index"] = $('.aws[name="item' + i + '"]').val()
  obj.push(temp);
}

console.log(obj);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="hidden" class="aws" name="item1" value="1.jpg">
<input type="hidden" class="aws" name="item2" value="2.jpg">
```

Comment: Why not use `.each()`?

Comment: Also, your second `class` does not match. Think you want both to be `aws`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add new object to array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9543805/add-new-object-to-array)

Comment: @Twisty that doesn't matter, it's just a typo

Comment: @PatrickEvans I'm getting `undefined`, it is not about object to array.

Comment: You are getting undefined because you are using the wrong length condition in your for loop, the bigger problem is that you are adding the same object to the array in each iteration so each object is going to be exactly the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're pushing a reference to the same object on each iteration. In doing so, the `index` property on the `temp` object will be the value from the last iteration.

In addition, there are only two elements, and the `for` loop was executed three times because of the condition `i <= len` (it should have been `i < len`). Due to this, the value was `undefined` on the last iteration, because the element doesn't exist. This resulted in all the `index` properties on the `temp` property being set to `undefined`.

If you want a native JS solution, you could simply use the following instead:

```
var elements = document.querySelectorAll('.aws');
var values = [];

for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
  values.push({index: elements[i].value});
}
```

In the snippet above, a new object is pushed to the `values` array on each iteration (rather than a reference to the same object). The `for` loop condition is also `i < elements.length` (rather than `i <= elements.length`), so it will only iterate 2 times (rather than 3 like in your example).

---

If you want a shorter jQuery solution, simply use the `.map()` method:

```
var values = $('.aws').map(function () {
  return {index: this.value };
}).get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/ys889cn6/1/

```
var obj = [],
  temp = {};

$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".aws").each(function(i, v) {
    obj.push({ "index": $(this).val() });
  });
  console.log(obj);
});
```

Much easier to loop this way. Read more: https://api.jquery.com/each/

**Somewhat Native**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var obj = [],
    temp = {},
  len = $('.aws').length;
  for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
  console.log("Get Value from: .aws[name='item" + (i+1) + "']");
    temp["index"] = $(".aws[name='item" + (i+1) + "']").val();
    obj.push(temp);
  }
  console.log(obj);
});
```

As @PatrickEvans stated, we're just dropping the same object in. Results:

```
Get Value from: .aws[name='item1']
Get Value from: .aws[name='item2']
[Object { index="2.jpg"}, Object { index="2.jpg"}]
```

Fixed by using:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var obj = [],
    temp = {},
  len = $('.aws').length;
  for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
  console.log("Get Value from: .aws[name='item" + (i+1) + "']");
    obj.push({"index": $(".aws[name='item" + (i+1) + "']").val()});
  }
  console.log(obj);
});
```

Comment: I know I can do this but why native JS have problem?

Comment: Why did you Post to Jquery if you wanted Native solution?

Comment: This is going to have the same problem, you are adding the same object in each iteration, you are overwriting the same property of the same object.

Comment: I suspect the issue with your native code comes in with the limit: `len = $('.aws').length + 1;`, this would be 3. When i is incremented, 0, 1, 2, 3... it will not have an object to find. Should be 2, with a < limit. 0, 1, those are all the items.

Comment: your  solution is broken, the value is repeated, 2.jpg twice.

Comment: Updated with more native code and a fix to the object logic.